# How to detect panic(nil) and normal execution in deferred function Go?

Tags: go, panic

The go runtime can detect `panic(nil)` and reports an error.

However, I can't detect `panic(nil)` with `recover()` in a `defer`red function because it returns `nil`, so I cannot differentiate it from normal execution (no panic) as I would test for
the return value of `recover()` to be nil.

For example,

```
defer func(){
    var err = recover()
    if err != nil {
       // Real serious situation. Panic from inner code.
       // And we may have some critical resources which 
       // must be cleaned-up at any cases.
       // However, this will not be executed for panic(nil) 

       rollback()

       // I am still not sure that how should I treat `panic`…
       // Should I just ignore them?
    }
}()

var err = doTransaction()
if err == nil {
    commit()    // Happy case.
} else {
    rollback()  // Regular execution. Just a lucky case.
}
```

ROLLBACK is just an example, and I think I can have plenty of critical cases needs cleanup. Well, those cleanup code won't be executed on real program crash too, but I want to defend as much as possible.

How can I detect any panic regardless of its parameter in a deferred function?

Comment: https://github.com/TheApeMachine/errnie/blob/master/v2/guard.go Place guard at top of a method, pass in your rollback function, defer a call to Rescue, panic away.

Comment: "Go 1.21 now defines that if a goroutine is panicking and recover was called directly by a deferred function, the return value of recover is guaranteed not to be nil. To ensure this, calling panic with a nil interface value (or an untyped nil) causes a run-time panic of type *runtime.PanicNilError." (https://go.dev/doc/go1.21)

Answer (score 5):

I simply can set a flag before exit.

AFAIK, panic is goroutine-specific, and single goroutine is guaranteed to be in single thread. So synchronization/locking is not required around variable `ok`. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

```
func clean(ok *bool) {
    if *ok {
        log.Printf("Execution OK. No panic detected.\n")
    } else {
        var reason = recover()
        log.Printf("Some bad thing happen. reason = %v\n", reason)
        panic("Abnormal exit. Program abandoned. Stack-trace here.")
        debug.PrintStack() // Oops. this will not run.
    }
}

func main() {
    var ok bool = false

    defer clean(&ok)
    panic(nil)

    test1() // Here's the main job.

    ok = true
    log.Printf("All work done. Quit gracefully.\n")
}
```

Comment: What's the use of having a flag which decides whether a **panic**, the last resort in error handling, is expected or not? What are you actually trying to achieve? This seems wrong on many levels.

Comment: @nemo In my case, I needed this to ROLLBACK any SQL command performed  in a block if any `panic()` get happen for any reason. I think this is classical *try..catch..clean and rethrow* strategy. Because there's no guarantee about some function *never panic* inside... Any better idea?

Comment: Please update your question with this information and explain why you are experiencing nil-panics.

Comment: @nemo I think you are missing the point: when one is running *any* code - especially third-party code - there may be `panic` events. Panic recovery allows one to ID specific error panics - but the problem is `r := recovery()` returns `nil` in the event of *no panic* or `panic(nil)` - and the OP (and I) would like to know if the latter occurred. The current recovery mechanism has no out of the box method to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the [proposal 25448](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25448) "spec: guarantee non-nil return value from recover" can help.

> Calling panic with a nil panic value is allowed in Go 1, but weird.
>
> Almost all code checks for panics with:
>
> ```golang
>      defer func() {
>         if e := recover(); e != nil { ... }
>      }()
> ```
>
> ... which is not correct in the case of `panic(nil)`.
>
> The proper way is more like:
>
> ```golang
>      panicked := true
>      defer func() {
>         if panicked {
>               e := recover()
>               ...
>         }
>      }()
>      ...
>      panicked = false
>      return
>      ....
>      panicked = false
>      return
> ```
>
> Proposal: make the runtime `panic` function promote its panic value from `nil` to something like a `runtime.NilPanic` global value of private, unassignable type:
>
> ```golang
> package runtime
>
> type nilPanic struct{}
>
> // NilPanic is the value returned by recover when code panics with a nil value.
> var NilPanic nilPanic
> ```

---

Proposed in 2018, it just [got accepted](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25448#issuecomment-1351988793) (Jan. 2023)

> The current proposal is that starting in Go 1.21 (say),
> `panic(nil)` turns into `panic(&runtime.PanicNil{})` during `panic` (so a variable that happens to be a `nil` interface does it too, not just the literal text `panic(nil)`).
>
> `panic(nil)` is always OK, but `recover()` returns `&runtime.PanicNil{}` instead of `nil` after this change.
> If `GODEBUG=panicnil=1`, then this change is disabled and `panic(nil)` causes `recover()` to return `nil` as it always has.
>
> Assuming [#56986](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/56986) ("proposal: extended backwards compatibility for Go") happens too in Go 1.21, this behavior would only change in modules that say '`go 1.21`' in the work module (top-level `go.mod`).
> So when you update from Go 1.20 to Go 1.21, without changing any `go.mod` lines, you'd still get the old `panic(nil)` behavior.
> When you change your top-level go.mod to say `go 1.21`, then you get the new behavior, in the whole program.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I misunderstood your question, deferred function calls *will* run when panicking, even if the value passed was `nil`. This is illustrated by the [following program](http://play.golang.org/p/dQtwlNrvLd):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("Recover:", recover())
    }()
    panic(nil)
}
```

You can therefore easily detect if `panic(nil)` happened by comparing the value returned by `recover()` to `nil`.

Edit to answer comment:

Yes, that's true; deferred calls will normally run when a function returns. But they are also run when unwinding the call-stack after a `panic()`.

Edit after question was updated:

You are correct that there is no way to differentiate these cases. On the other hand, panicking with `nil` doesn't make much sense either - especially because of this limitation.

The only use-case for `panic(nil)` that I could think of would be to deliberately avoid recovery and force the program to crash with a stack trace. There are more elegant ways to do that though, using the `runtime` package for instance.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry for unclear question. What I wanted was differentiating `panic(nil)` and normal execution in `defer`red function…

Comment: Maybe I can just set a flag before exit the function.

Answer (score 2):

For most cases, the idiomatic way of `if recover() != nil` works, but for robustness, or when executing third-party code, it should not be used, because it does not detect `panic(nil)`.

This pattern is how you can check it:

```golang
func checkPanic(action func()) (panicked bool, panicMsg interface{}) {
    panicked = true
    defer func() { panicMsg = recover() }
    action()
    panicked = false
    return
}
```

If `action()` panics, then the line below is never executed, and `panicked` stays true.
You can check it using the above helper function as follows:

```golang
if panicked, msg := checkPanic(func() { /* ... */ }); panicked {
    // handle panic...
} else {
    // happy case :D
}
```

Or you can directly implement the pattern into the function you want to check, but it might turn out way messier that way.

Answer (score 0):

With Go 1.21 it seems `panic(nil)` no longer panics with `nil` as pointed out by VonC. As I'm still using Go 1.20, I decided to try [RmbRT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71497952/8228163). As I found it harder to use than the way I was using (without catching `nil` panics), I decided to instead modify it (a Try/Catch/Finally from [Peter Verhas](https://dzone.com/users/1088343/verhas.html)) with RmbRT's answer. It works. Detects nil and non-nil panics, and differentiates that from function returns normally (`recover()` returns `nil`).

Here is the code:

```golang
type Exception interface{}

func Throw(up Exception) {
    panic(up)
}

func (tcef Tcef) Do() {
    var panicked bool = true

    if tcef.Finally != nil {
        defer tcef.Finally()
    }
    if tcef.Else != nil {
        defer func() {
            if !panicked {
                tcef.Else()
            }
        }()
    }
    if tcef.Catch != nil {
        defer func() {
            if panicked {
                tcef.Catch(recover())
            }
        }()
    }

    tcef.Try()
    panicked = false
}

type Tcef struct {
    Try     func()
    Catch   func(Exception)
    Else    func()
    Finally func()
}
```

Most of the credits go to Peter (if you see this, thank you so much, I love this solution), I just added a new idea to it. Here is the original version: https://dzone.com/articles/try-and-catch-in-golang. An example of how to use this is also in this page.

**EDIT:** since I added RmbRT's `panicked` idea to it, I decided to have it be like Python's case. So I added the Else clause, that only executes if no "Exception" was thrown, and in Python's order (Try/Except(Catch)/Else/Finally).

Comment: Nicely done, upvoted. Seeing `interface{}` (also [known as `any`](https://medium.com/@csaba.ujvari/go-1-18-any-instead-of-interface-ce15dd7bea5d)), I wondered if your code could benefit from generics. In the case of your `Tcf` type and associated functions, it is designed to be very general, catching and handling any kind of panic, whether it is a `nil` value, a string, an error, or any other type of value. So... no: given its general nature, it is not immediately clear how generics would be help.

Comment: @Edw590 I don't get what problem you encountered with my answer's solution. Could you clarify that? Because I use patterns like that in production and it seems to work for me.

Comment: @RmbRT Hi. I've been trying for a bit, to test various ways of panicking with your solution: and I have no idea why I said it didn't work... Sorry for the confusion. Strange. I'll edit my answer and remove that part. Yours works with all attempts I just tried. Maybe I meant to say that I found it "harder" to use than the way I was using and tried to merge it with yours. Maybe was that. Sometimes I don't think too much I guess. If by chance I remember why I said that, I'll say here.

Comment: Cool. thank you. I was worried for a moment.